# Using an asterisk to precede the zip function

Tags: python, numpy

The below code is from Jake VanderPlas's book "Python Data Science Handbook":

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(42)
X = rand.rand(10,2)
dist_sq = np.sum(X[:,np.newaxis,:] - X[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2, axis=-1)    

K=2
nearest_partition = np.argpartition(dist_sq, K + 1, axis=1)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=100)
# draw lines from each point to its two nearest neighbors
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    for j in nearest_partition[i, :K+1]:
        # plot a line from X[i] to X[j]
        # use some zip magic to make it happen:
        plt.plot(*zip(X[j], X[i]), color='black')
```

A few questions:

1. I've seen the asterisk used inside the zip function to unpack tuples but have not seen it used to precede a function call like zip.  What is the right way to understand the use of the asterisk in this manner?
2. To try and understand what was happening, I looked at the results of `print(*zip(X[j], X[i])` and it seems that the X & Y coordinates from each point are unpacked and zipped together such that there are two tuples.  Why is that the right logic here?  Also, what is the right way to understand how the plot function is handling/interpreting each pair of tuples?  I've never seen a pair of tuples passed in such a way to the plot function.

Comment: It is used for any generator/iterable, not just zip.  It unpacks the list-like object into individual entries.  I personally use it all the time to print lists of strings: e.g. `print(*string_list,sep='\n')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider two points, `a` and `b`.

```py
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
```

When we zip them we get:

```py
print(list(zip(a, b))) # [[1,3], [2,4]]
```

We can see that the first element of each are paired together, and similarly for the second element of each. This is just how zip works; I suspect this makes sense for you. If those are (x,y) points, then we've just grouped the x's and y's together.

Now; consider the signature of `plt.plot(x, y, ...)`. It expects the first argument to be all the x's, and the second argument to be all the y's. Well, the zip just grouped those together for us! We can use the `*` operator to spread those over the first two arguments. Notice that these are equivalent operations:

```py
p = list(zip(a, b))
plt.plot(*p)
plt.plot(p[0], p[1])
```

Side note: to expand to more points we just add the extra points into the zip:

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
print(list(zip(a, b, c))) # [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
plt.plot(*zip(a, b, c)) # plots the 3 points
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` inside a function call converts a list (or other iterable) into a `*args` kind of argument.

`zip` with several lists iterates through them pairing up elements:

```
In [1]: list(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
Out[1]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

If we define a list:

```
In [2]: alist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
In [3]: list(zip(alist))
Out[3]: [([1, 2, 3],), ([4, 5, 6],)]
```

That `zip` didn't do much.  But if we star it:

```
In [4]: list(zip(*alist))
Out[4]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Check the `zip` docs - see the `*args`:

```
In [5]: zip?
Init signature: zip(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
zip(*iterables) --> A zip object yielding tuples until an input is exhausted.

   >>> list(zip('abcdefg', range(3), range(4)))
   [('a', 0, 0), ('b', 1, 1), ('c', 2, 2)]

The zip object yields n-length tuples, where n is the number of iterables
passed as positional arguments to zip().  The i-th element in every tuple
comes from the i-th iterable argument to zip().  This continues until the
shortest argument is exhausted.
Type:           type
Subclasses:
```

`*` could also be used with a function like `def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3):...`

In `plt.plot(*zip(X[j], X[i]), color='black')`, `plot` has signature like `plot(x, y, kwargs)`.  I don't think this is any different from

```
plt.plot(X[j], X[i], color='black')
```

but I'd have to actually test some code.

### edit

```
def foo(x,y):
    print(x,y)

In [11]: X = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
In [12]: foo(X[1],X[0])
[2 3] [0 1]
In [13]: foo(*zip(X[1],X[0]))
(2, 0) (3, 1)
```

`list(*zip(...))` is a list version of a matrix transpose.

Comment: It is different; `X[i]` is an `(x,y)` tuple, but the plot expects all the x's together and all the y's together.

Comment: Actually, `*zip()` is a list/tuple form of matrix transpose.  See my edit that tests with a simple print function.

Comment: Your example shows precisely how `plt.plot(X[j], X[i])` and `plt.plot(*zip(X[j], X[i]))` are different...